# what does this Notice: Use of undefined constant pageTitle - assumed 'pageTitle' mean

Tags: php

I have in my page on the top i have defined some variables like so

```
define(pageTitle , "Home Page");
define(pageDescription, "Key Descriptin");
define(pageKeywords, "Key words");
```

later in my code I include a meta file which uses those variables.  But I get this notice in my page

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant pageTitle - assumed 'pageTitle' 
Notice: Use of undefined constant pageDescription - assumed 'pageDescription'
Notice: Use of undefined constant pageKeywords - assumed 'pageKeywords' in
```

What does this mean? how can i correct those?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put quotes around your constant names:

```
define('pageTitle' , "Home Page");
define('pageDescription', "Key Descriptin");
define('pageKeywords', "Key words");
```

Comment: Thanks :)  what about this error Notice: Undefined index: action it is referring to this line $action = $_GET['action'];

Comment: It means there was no parameter called `action` in your query string

Comment: I can't say without seeing code. But since it is supposed to be in your query string, make sure whatever generates the query string is including it properly.